# I have trashed my system so only see a xfce dexktop session instead of kde

Tags: kubuntu, kde, sddm

I managed to trash my Kubuntu system, by some silly apt removal and attempt to correct the mistake, so now at login all I get is a xfce session, which hangs after I enter my password.

I can switch out to a shell and login to the system, so how can I repair my gui login to get KDE back.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop`. Hope that is what you mean by "my gui".

Comment: @mikewhatever tyvm that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

@mikewhatever gave me the solution which was to install kubuntu-desktop